# how to get list of selected row or list of selected checkbox from jsp page to action class method of portlet in liferay 6?

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet, checkbox, liferay-6

I am developing custom portlet and in one of my view page I need some help.

Following is my form in which I have check box in every row and each row will be created at run time (dynamically):

```
<form method="post" name="editform">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dt_gal_res">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th class="table_checkbox"><input type="checkbox"
                    name="select_rows" class="select_rows"
                    data-tableid="dt_gal_rest" /></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contact Person</th>
            <th>Website</th>
            <th>EDIT</th>
            <th>DELETE</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>

 <%
       List<restaurant> rest_listOBJ = restaurantLocalServiceUtil.getAllAvailableRestaurant();

       for (int i = 0; i < (rest_listOBJ.size()); i++) {
                restaurant temprest = rest_listOBJ.get(i);
  %>

     <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="row_sel" class="row_sel" /></td>
            <td><%=temprest.getName() %></td>
            <td><%=temprest.getContactno() %></td>
            <td><%=temprest.getWebsite() %></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="1" value="edit"
                            onclick="return getbuttonId('<%=temprest.getPrimaryKey() %>')" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="2" value="DELETE"
                            onclick="return getdeletebuttonId('<%=temprest.getPrimaryKey() %>')" />
                </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
        <%
            }
        %>
</table>

    <div style="visibility: hidden;">
        <input type="hidden" name="hide1" id="hiddenkey" value="">
    </div>
</form>
```

Right now I have delete button and by some other logic I am deleting the row one by one.
But now what I want is that after selecting the check-box of rows one or more check box when
I submit one button then on-click of that one button I want to delete all those rows for which check-box is selected.

Somehow if anyone can guide me that how can I get list of selected check box list in my action method of portlet class then even that will be enough for me.

I am quite new to jsp so any one who has any idea please suggest me.

As u guyz suggested i have done same way.but not getting any success..please correct me where am wrong here is my action class

```
public void deleteMultipleRestaurant(ActionRequest ar, ActionResponse ap)
            throws Exception {

        log.info("ENTERED");
        List<restaurant> restaurants = restaurantLocalServiceUtil.getAllAvailableRestaurant();



        for (restaurant restaurantitem : restaurants) {        
            if (Boolean.valueOf(ar.getParameter("row_sel" + restaurantitem.getPrimaryKey()))) {
               // This is a selected checkbox so add you remove code here

                log.info(restaurantitem);

                restaurantitem.setIsdeleted(true);
                restaurantLocalServiceUtil.updaterestaurant(restaurantitem);


            }
        }
    }
```

in my view file am doing as follows

this is my one of ul in this my delete link is there

```
<portlet:actionURL name="deleteMultipleRestaurant"
                        var="multideleteURL">
                    </portlet:actionURL>

                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
                        Action <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">                          
                        <li><aui:button name="DELETE" value="DELETE" onClick="<%=multideleteURL.toString() %>"/></li>                           
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

following is  in view page

```
<tbody>
                                <%
                                    List<restaurant> rest_listOBJ = restaurantLocalServiceUtil
                                                                    .getAllAvailableRestaurant();

                                                              for (int i = 0; i < (rest_listOBJ.size()); i++) {

                                                                restaurant temprest = rest_listOBJ.get(i);
        %>

<tr>                                            
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="row_sel<%= temprest.getPrimaryKey() %>" name="<portlet:namespace/>row_sel<%= temprest.getPrimaryKey() %>" class="row_sel" />
      </td>

    <td><%=temprest.getName()%></td>
    <td><%=temprest.getContactno()%></td>
    <td><%=temprest.getWebsite()%></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="1"
                                            onclick="return getbuttonId('<%=temprest.getPrimaryKey()%>')"
                                            style="border:none;width:20px" class="icon-pencil"/>
                                        <input type="button" id="2"
                                            onclick="return getdeletebuttonId('<%=temprest.getPrimaryKey()%>')"
                                            style="border:none;width:20px" class="icon-trash" /></td>
                                    </tr>                               
                                <%
                                    }
                                %>
                            </tbody>
```

but nothing am getting..its just reloading the page..just dat

Comment: Can you add the '<form>' tag to your update, or check that the Form's action is <%=multideleteURL%>. Also could you add what show's in your Logs, as you're using logging.

Comment: ya.the condition if (Boolean.valueOf(ar.getParameter("row_sel" + restaurantitem.getPrimaryKey()))) {
               never being true.so that means somehow very check box value coming false

Comment: when i put log there of the above condition it has came false

Comment: I've added another edit to my answer which is a code snippet that will print all the parameters to the log, and tell you their values. This should give you a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't know it was just done in this simple way. Correct me if I am wrong. I just solved my problem with the following code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="row_sel" class="row_sel" /></td>
```

and in my action method

```
String[] camp_id = request.getParameterValues("row_sel");
// boolean booln = false;

for(String camp_iditem:camp_id){ ... }
```

and it just gives me the value of the checked button in `camp_iditem` variable.

I just got what I wanted to do. Please correct me if I am doing wrong?

Thanks to all for your guidance ..

Answer (score 4):

Now you are doing:

1. Sending single `Id` to the `processAction` method
2. Executing the action based on the button `edit` or `delete`

You want:

1. Select multiple check-boxes
2. Click `Delete` button somewhere
3. All the selected items gets deleted

Solution (there might be many other ways):

1. You checkbox should be like this:

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="<portlet:namespace/>row_sel" class="row_sel" value="<%=temprest.getPrimaryKey() %>" />
   ```

   If you use `<aui:input />` tags you won't have to bother about prepending the `name` attribute with `<portlet:namespace/>`
2. Collecting all the `Id`s in a hidden input field `<input type="hidden" name="<portlet:namespace/>allCheckedIds" />` with comma-separated format and then sending it to the server.
3. This can be done using javascript, on click of the `Delete` button call a javascript method which would construct a string of all the `Id`s from the checked check-box's values. You can take help of [this link](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-check.phtml) to construct the javascript method.
4. Then `submit` the `form` with the help of the javascript method itself.
5. Then in your `processAction` method you can separate the `Id`s from the comma-separated string received as:

   ```
   String allIds = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "allCheckedIds");
   //allIds = "1,2,3,4,5,6"; // this is how the Ids might look
   long[] idArray = StringUtil.split(allIds, ",", 0); // were 0 is the default value
   ```
6. Now pass these Ids to the service layer to delete them.

That's it. Simple isn't it.

There is also a similar method used by liferay, you can check the `Document Library Display` portlet for this. If you use `<liferay-ui:searchContainer>` to display your list then you can take advantage of how liferay does this for you.

I will provide some pointers in this direction, you can check the source:
[`view_file_entries.jspf`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library_display/view_file_entries.jspf), check out the line [`rowChecker="<%= entriesChecker %>"`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library_display/view_file_entries.jspf#L43) whick creates the check-boxes for you and then check-out [`'<portlet:namespace />deleteEntries'][4],` javascript method which actually sends the request to the action class. There are jsps and action classes which you can check-out, but I will that upto you to explore. :-)

Happy Exploring.

Comment: thanks a lot...just started to implementing as u said....give u feedback as soon as i complete this...thanks again

Comment: i either do this way.but just done with the following way..thanks for detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is change the name attribute and add an id attribute to your your checkboxes. So instead of having this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="row_sel" class="row_sel" /></td>
```

You should have something like this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="row_sel<%= temprest.getPrimaryKey() %>" name="<portlet:namespace/>row_sel<%= temprest.getPrimaryKey() %>" class="row_sel" /></td>
```

This will ensure each of the checkboxes can be uniquely identified in your processAction method.

Then in your process action method you can use the following logic to find out if a checkbox was selected or not:

```
List<Restaurant> restaurants = RestaurantLocalServiceUtil.getAllAvailableRestaurant();

for (Restaurant restaurant : restaurants) {        
    if (Boolean.valueOf(actionRequest.getParameter("row_sel" + restaurant.getPrimaryKey())) {
       // This is a selected checkbox so add you remove code here
    }
}
```

That should do the trick for you in a rough way!

Also if this answer (or any other answer to one of your questions) help you please "Accept" that answer to help the community, and acknowledge the people who are taking the time to help you out.

~~ EDIT ~~

Also as Olaf has mentioned below your `<form>` tag should be as follows:

```
<form method="post" name="editform" action="<portlet:actionURL/>">
```

~~ EDIT 02/11/12 ~~

The following code can be used to see all the parameters being passed to the Action method, and their values:

```
for (String key : actionRequest.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
    log.info("Param " + key + " has value: " + actionRequest.getParameter(key));
}
```

Comment: The name for the checkbox should be 'name="<portlet:namespace/>row_sel<%= temprest.getPrimaryKey() %>"' and the form should post to <portlet:actionURL/>

Comment: Thanks Olaf. I've added updated my answer with amendment to the name.

Comment: @Jonny I have rolled-back the question edit you did. I think it would benefit to notify the user what to use instead of changing the question itself.

Comment: @PrakashK Fair do's. I more didn't want that very useful information to be lost in the comments.

Comment: @Jonny add it to your answer then.

Comment: @PrakashK Normally you just go and do it anyway! ;-)

Comment: please take a look at my updated question at the end of question.having some issue